# setTimeout dentro de setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

Há uma maneira de fazer isso no Node.js?

`setInterval` (a cada 5 segundos)

Algumas funções (mais ou menos 3 - 4 segundos)

`setTimeout` (3 segundos)

Fim

Então a cada 5 segundos executam uma função que eu não sei quanto tempo vai gastar como eu faço isso?

Ex:

```
setInterval(() => {

        this.tradeApi.getAccountInfo((acountInfo) => {
            if (acountInfo.balance.brl.available > this.config.invest) {
                console.log(chalk.yellow("Aguardando saldo para operar..."));
            } else {
                this.infoApi.ticker((ticker) => {
                    console.log(chalk.cyan("O valor da moeda esta: ") + chalk.green("R$ " + Number(ticker.ticker.last).toFixed(5)));
                    console.log(chalk.cyan("Estou colocando uma ordem de compra a: ") + chalk.green("R$ " + Number(ticker.ticker.last / this.config.decay).toFixed(5)) + chalk.cyan(" por " + process.env.CRAWLER_INTERVAL + " segundos e ver se vende..."));

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log("esperei 5 s");
                    }, process.env.CRAWLER_INTERVAL)

                })
            }
        })


    }, process.env.CRAWLER_INTERVAL)
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está pouco clara. Poderia explicar um pouco melhor? Você já chegou a elaborar algum código tentando implementar isso?

Comment: Ao invés de fazer dessa forma, pq não executa a tarefa, espera X minutos e executa novamente? Sem se importar com quanto tempo demora. Por exemplo: `loop infinito { executa_tarefa(); esperarMinutos(5) }`